# Extending the Elm tutorial form app to include a numbered input Age

Tags: elm

I've been following this tutorial: http://guide.elm-lang.org/architecture/user_input/forms.html

The text there makes sense to me, my question pertains to the exercise it lists at the bottom of the page. It asks that I:

> "Add an additional field for age and check that it is a number."

I am having difficulty with this because the `onInput` function seems to only accept a String input. I find it odd that there is no equivalent for `type="number"` inputs.

Nevertheless, this is my attempt which does not work:

```hs
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.App as Html
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (onInput)
import String exposing (length)

main =
  Html.beginnerProgram { model = model, view = view, update = update }


-- MODEL

type alias Model =
  { name : String
  , password : String
  , passwordAgain : String
  , age : Int
  }


model : Model
model =
  Model "" "" "" 0


-- UPDATE

type Msg
    = Name String
    | Password String
    | PasswordAgain String
    | Age Int

update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
  case msg of
    Name name ->
      { model | name = name }

    Password password ->
      { model | password = password }

    PasswordAgain password ->
      { model | passwordAgain = password }

    Age age ->
      { model | age = age }      


-- VIEW

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ input [ type' "text", placeholder "Name", onInput Name ] []
    , input [ type' "password", placeholder "Password", onInput Password ] []
    , input [ type' "password", placeholder "Re-enter Password", onInput PasswordAgain ] []
    , input [ type' "number", placeholder "Age", onInput Age ] []
    , viewValidation model
    ]

viewValidation : Model -> Html msg
viewValidation model =
  let
    (color, message) =
      if model.password /= model.passwordAgain then
        ("red", "Passwords do not match!")
      else if length model.password <= 8 then
        ("red", "Password must be more than 8 characters!")
      else
        ("green", "OK")
  in
    div [ style [("color", color)] ] [ text message ]
```

The error I get is the following:

```
-- TYPE MISMATCH ----------------------------------------------------- forms.elm

The argument to function `onInput` is causing a mismatch.

58|                                                  onInput Age 
                                                             ^^^
Function `onInput` is expecting the argument to be:

    String -> a

But it is:

    Int -> Msg
```

Note: I am aware that I could create the Age input as just another text input, but the exercise specifically asked me to check that it is a `number type. I assume this means I should hold it inside the model as an Int.

I am clear about what the error is. I simply want to know the idiomatic way to fix this in Elm. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any user-input from `onInput` event is a String.

Your `Model` expects it to be an `Int`

Use [String.toInt](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.5/String#toInt) to parse the integer value from a string value.

Adjust `update` function to convert the type to an `Int` and change the type signature to `Age String`

```
Age age ->
    case String.toInt age of
        Ok val ->
            { model | age = val }

        -- Notify the user, or simply ignore the value
        Err err ->
            model
```

That way you have an option to notify the user about the error.

In case if `Maybe` value suits you better, the whole statement can be simplified to:

```
Age age ->
    { model | age =  Result.toMaybe (String.toInt age) }
```

Comment: The problem i see with this is that error-notification should happen in the `view`-function, not in the `update`-function. A possible solution for this is to make `age` in the Model a `Result string int` but this is also rather ugly...

Comment: Perhaps making `age` a `Maybe Int` makes more sense... Then in the view when `age == Nothing` you can still display an appropriate error.

Comment: This is a working solution with that strategy : http://share-elm.com/sprout/57b3b389e4b075621ead4593

Comment: @hansvb fair enough, please check the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the equivalent of `onInput` but for one that operates on integers. Based on how `targetValue` is defined, you can do something similar with the addition of `Json.Decode.int` to parse it as an integer:

```elm
onIntInput : (Int -> msg) -> Attribute msg
onIntInput tagger =
  Html.Events.on "input" (Json.map tagger (Json.at ["target", "value"] Json.int))
```

You can then use it as such:

```elm
, input [ type' "number", placeholder "Age", onIntInput Age ] []
```